# PYSON domain search referencing fields of current user

Tags: python, tryton

I'm using GNU Health on Tryton and want to do a domain search in a view using PYSON and fields related to the current user. The problem is that I don't know how to reference the fields related to the current user.

I want to check if the user `is_healthprof` and if that's the case filter using the lastname field of the current user as health professional lastname so that the user will only see the data related to him. I tried the following code in my xml view file but as I don't know how to do the trick is not working.

```
<field name="domain">[('appointment_date', '>=', DateTime(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)),(If(Eval('party.party.is_healthprof', -1),('healthprof.lastname','=',party.party.lastname)))]</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a domain you should add an access rule that depends on the is_healthproft flag of the user. See:

http://doc.tryton.org/3.8/trytond/doc/topics/access_rights.html?highlight=access

Using access rules will enforce the domain for every operation on the model, so if the user accesses the model for a relation field or for a different action, the access rule will also apply.

BTW, instead of creating a flag in the user to indicate if is healthproft, i think it's better to create a user group for Healtproft and associate the users with this group (and so the access group).

Hope it helps.

Comment: So just add the acces rule (as mentioned in the doc) to this user group.

Comment: I did as you said but I'm not able to reference the proper 'id'. I added the domain [('healthprof', '=', user.id)] but the 'id' I get is the one included at the the table res_user as an internal user. I have to reference to the one included in the gnuhealth_healthprofessional table (gnuhealth_healthprofessional.id) that is linked to party_party.id by gnuhealth_healthprofessional.name. The id at party_party is connected to the internal user by party_party.internal_user. I tried to follow the documentation but I'm a newbie and can't make it work. Thanks in advanced

Comment: You have to use the relations to get the proper id. Something like: [('healthprof', '=', user.party.gnu_professional.id)]

Comment: Thanks pokoli but I can't make it work. Anyway, trying to find a workaround, do you know how can I get the party.id if we have, as in this case, the user.id?

Comment: The only way to access the party is through the relations as I explained in the previous message.

Comment: I tried with [('healthprof', '=', user.party.gnu_professional.id)]  as explained but it's not working. I also tried [('healthprof', '=', user.party.id)] and [('healthprof', '=', user.party_party.id)] but they don't work as the previous example. I've also tried with eval but I don't really understand how it works and I always get the message 'The domain of the rule is incorrect'. That's why I asked the example to get the party id as an example of referring to a child in order to understand how to use relations